# Edit the Style of a ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have the following style for the ScrollViewer of a ListBox but I don't know where to put it in my ListBox's xaml :

```
<Style x:key"Style1" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
            <Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Disabled"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ScrollStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="00:00:00.5"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Scrolling">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="NotScrolling"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Grid Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="Auto" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="5"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="HorizontalScrollBar" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="5" IsHitTestVisible="False" IsTabStop="False" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" Minimum="0" Opacity="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Where Do I have to add this in my ListBox to customize the ScrollViewer ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the default list box style: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754242(v=vs.110).aspx You will notice it has a scroll viewer as part of the ControlTemplate.  You will need to target the scroll viewer style in the list box control template like so:

```
  <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBox">
    <Border Name="Border"
            BorderThickness="1"
            CornerRadius="2">
      <Border.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource ControlLightColor}" />
      </Border.Background>
      <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BorderMediumColor}" />
      </Border.BorderBrush>
      <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource Style1}" Margin="0"
                    Focusable="false">
        <StackPanel Margin="2"
                    IsItemsHost="True" />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
```

Comment: Ok but where will I have to mention it in my ListBox ?  At the beggining : <ListBox  [Here]  />   Or somewhere here : <ListBox>[Here]<ListBox/>  ?